# Executing a shell script to run python script remotely but not stopping for prompts

Tags: bash, ssh

Executing a python script located on a remote machine. Python script prompts to ask for the option. While running using the following code, execution finishes with stopping/pausing for the prompt.

```
ssh -t xyz@111.111.111.111 << EOF
    python script.py --user username --password pwrd --option xyzlmn
EOF
```

Comment: What option is the script prompting you for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your python script wants to read from its stdin.

It obtains its stdin from ssh.

ssh has been set so that its stdin is the heredoc (EOF..EOF).

So python attempts to read from the heredoc but there is nothing to read.

Pass the python command as arguments to ssh instead, so that ssh's stdin is still the tty:

```
ssh xyz@111.111.111.111 '
    python script.py --user username --password pwrd --option xyzlmn
'
```